# How to change an element in a multidimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I've created a mutidimensional array like this:
`let array = new Array(7).fill(Array(7).fill());`

Then I tried to change `array[0][0]`, like this:
`array[0][0] = 1;`

But somehow, this changes the first element of every inner array.
This is the output I've got:

```
Array(7)
0: (7) [1, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
1: (7) [1, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
2: (7) [1, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
3: (7) [1, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
4: (7) [1, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
5: (7) [1, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
6: (7) [1, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

I can't imagine what I did wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
const newArr = (a, b) => {
  return Array.from({length: a}, (_, i) => {
    return Array.from({length: b}, (_, j) => {
      return [i, j]
    })
  })
}
console.log(newArr(4, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same array reference when filling with the array. Instead use a .map() to fill instead.

```
const arr2D = Array(7).fill(0).map(()=> Array(7).fill(0));
```